# ¿Cómo deseleccionar un checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="well">
  <h2>Select you files</h2>
  <table id="list-files" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th width="10px"><input type="checkbox" id="select-all-files" checked="checked"></th>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>Size</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="0" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[0]" value="tuSITIO.com.txt"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>34.0 iB</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="1" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[1]" value="The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.mkv"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>8.8 GiB</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="2" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[2]" value="The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.nfo"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>5.4 KiB</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Como hago para deseleccionar solo el checkbox asociado al input con valor **tuSITIO.com.txt** utilizando jQuery?

Mi `script`:

```
$("input:checkbox[value=1]").removeAttr("checked");
```

Como notarán mi `script` apunta a inputs de tipo checkbox con `value=1` (orden donde se encuentra, en este caso, el archivo .txt). Sin embargo, el orden del archivo `tuSITIO.com.txt` suele cambiar a `value=0, value=2, etc`, por lo que ese selector no es correcto en todos los casos.

¿Como lo resolverían ustedes?

Comment: Si la segunda posición no es siempre garantizada ¿Por que no simplemente asignarle un id para seleccionarlo y manipularlo? Al menos el valor del input "tuSITIO.com.txt" es fijo?

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que nada no hay garantía que el `checkbox` se encuentre en la segunda posición tienes al menos dos opciones.

1. Primera y mas sencilla, asignarle un `id` al checkbox, obtenerlo por `id` y setear su propiedad `checked` con su valor opuesto.
2. Si por alguna extraña razón no puedes setearle un id pero si se va a respetar la estructura del html y el valor del input puedes:

   - Obtener el input a partir de su valor `"tuSITIO.com.txt"`
   - Otener el `td` padre, recorriendo los ancestros hasta llegar a un `tr`, sin incluirlo mediante `.parentsUntil()`
   - Estando en el `td` padre obtener su `td` hermano
   - Estando en el `td` hermano obtener su hijo `checkbox`
   - Manipular el atributo `checked` de dicho hijo

Esta segunda opción no es recomendable ya que se es compleja innecesariamente y puede ser afectada por cambios en tu arbol del documento; mientras que la opción 1 no.

```js
// 1
$("#uncheck-id").on("click", function(){
    let tuSitioCheckbox = $("#tusitiocheckbox");
    tuSitioCheckbox.prop("checked", !tuSitioCheckbox.prop("checked"));
});

// 2
$("#uncheck").on("click", function(){
   let parentTd = $("input[value='tuSITIO.com.txt']").parentsUntil("tr")[2]; // por la estructura sabemos que el hijo 0 es span, hijo 1 es div e hijo 2 es td.
   let siblingTd = $(parentTd).siblings()[0];
   let matchingCheckbox = $(siblingTd).children()[0];
   let currentValue = $(matchingCheckbox).prop("checked");
   $(matchingCheckbox).prop("checked", !currentValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well">
  <h2>Select you files</h2>
  <table id="list-files" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th width="10px"><input type="checkbox" id="select-all-files" checked="checked"></th>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>Size</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
      <td><input id="tusitiocheckbox" type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="0" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[0]" value="tuSITIO.com.txt"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>34.0 iB</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="1" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[1]" value="The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.mkv"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>8.8 GiB</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="2" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[2]" value="The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.nfo"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>5.4 KiB</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
<button id="uncheck-id"> 1) Click me to uncheck by id </button>
  <button id="uncheck"> 2) Click me to uncheck traversing ancestors </button>

</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la elaborada respuesta y perdon por la tardía respuesta, no pude ingresar sino hasta ahora. Como podria aplicar ese comando, el primero por ej, en Tampermonkey? es para el sitio: https://multiup.org/en/upload/from-torrent

Comment: Es simplemente JQuery, puedes hacerlo con javascript vanilla tambien. Lo que quieres hacer es agregar ese script en Tampermonkey para que se active en multiup? Tu controlas el DOM de multiup o quieres injectar scripts con Tampermonkey? Porque si controlas el DOM es simplemente agregarle un id al checkbox que quieras y agregar el script, de no ser asi debes ver como esta hecha la estructura de multiup para ver si puedes tener un id o buscar otra solucion. No me queda claro que intentas hacer.

Comment: soy bastante iniciado en  esto, pero ya tengo solucionado este problema, si no logré ser lo suficientemente claro en el post entonces no puedo explicarlo

lo unico q puedo decir es q tu código funciona cuando lo pruebo acá pero cuando lo cargo en Tampermonkey en el sitio donde realmente quiero q funcione no lo hace. pero de todos formas hice otra pregunto y esto ya está listo, grax

Comment: Bien, si, deberias enfocarte en ver como utilizar Tampermonkey, quiza puedas comenzar con un script mas sencillo (estilo console.log("Hello world") y luego ya vas viendo :)

Comment: Tampermonkey es facil, lo dificil son los script jaja, Tampermonkey me interesa por lo q puede lograr pero tratar de entenderlo requiere un interés más amplio del que estoy teniendo. por ahora solo busco preguntas similares a las mías en el foro ingles y copio y pruebo